# openvz quota error on gentoo

Tags: gentoo, openvz, virtual-machines

My system is Gentoo amd64, with latest update. I emerged the latest openvz, and want to start a Ubuntu VPS on my system. I am using the 'basic' configuration file, and the quota options are set as default, as follow:

`DISKSPACE="1048576:1153024"`
`DISKINODES="200000:220000"`
`QUOTATIME="0"`

If I try to create a CT, I will get the following error message.

```
Creating container private area (ubuntu-10.04-x86_64)
/usr/lib64/vzctl/scripts/vps-create: line 31: 13037 Killed                  
tar -C "$VE_PRVT" ${TAR_OPT} ${OPT} -xf "$PRIVATE_TEMPLATE"
vps-create ERROR: Error in tar --numeric-owner -z -xf /vz/template/cache/ubuntu-10.04-x86_64.tar.gz
Received signal:  9 in /usr/sbin/vzquota
Killed
```

the system may appear to be alive, but as soon as there is any IO action, like open a file with vim, the system hangs.

i am really new to openvz, and have no idea where should i start to troubleshoot this problem.

below is the dmesg output: (the system hangs after that message, so i am not sure if it is the complete output)

```
[  172.196141] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (null)
[  172.196582] IP: [<(null)>] (null)
[  172.196820] PGD 12e353067 PUD 12c73b067 PMD 0
[  172.197002] Oops: 0010 [#1] SMP
[  172.197002] last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/net/venet0/uevent
[  172.197002] CPU 0
[  172.197002] Modules linked in: vznetdev vzrst vzcpt vzdquota vzmon vzdev sco rfcomm bnep l2cap btusb bluetooth [last unloaded: i2c_nforce2]
[  172.197002] Pid: 2246, comm: tar Not tainted 2.6.32-openvz-budarin.1 #14 budarin System Product Name
[  172.197002] RIP: 0010:[<0000000000000000>]  [<(null)>] (null)
[  172.197002] RSP: 0018:ffff88012be5b990  EFLAGS: 00010246
[  172.197002] RAX: ffffffffa00899c0 RBX: ffff88012b4ffad0 RCX: 000000000000000c
[  172.197002] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000003000 RDI: ffff88012b4ffad0
[  172.197002] RBP: ffff88012be5b9f8 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 0000000000000000
[  172.197002] R10: 00000000000001dc R11: dead000000200200 R12: ffff88012b4b0850
[  172.197002] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff88012b4ffa20 R15: ffff88012b4ffdc8
[  172.197002] FS:  00007ffd298d4700(0000) GS:ffff880028200000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  172.197002] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  172.197002] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 000000012cc8e000 CR4: 00000000000006b0
[  172.197002] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[  172.197002] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[  172.197002] Process tar (pid: 2246, veid=0, threadinfo ffff88012be5a000, task ffff88012c62edb0)
[  172.197002] Stack:
[  172.197002]  ffffffff81137cb8 ffff88012e067c00 0000000000000002 0000000000000003
[  172.197002] <0> ffffffffffff0000 ffff88012b4ffad0 0000000000000000 ffff88012be5b9f8
[  172.197002] <0> ffffea0004a83bc0 0000000000000800 0000000000001000 ffff88012be5ba98
[  172.197002] Call Trace:
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff81137cb8>] ? ext4_da_get_block_prep+0x138/0x28c
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff810dbbcd>] __block_prepare_write+0x1b2/0x392
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff81137b80>] ? ext4_da_get_block_prep+0x0/0x28c
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff81085011>] ? add_to_page_cache_locked+0x75/0xb6
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff810dbf2e>] block_write_begin+0x7b/0xcd
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff811378a7>] ext4_da_write_begin+0x15b/0x1e8
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff81137b80>] ? ext4_da_get_block_prep+0x0/0x28c
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff81085a1a>] generic_file_buffered_write+0x104/0x275
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff81086040>] __generic_file_aio_write+0x34d/0x382
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff810860d3>] generic_file_aio_write+0x5e/0xa8
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff8112f289>] ext4_file_write+0x89/0x90
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff810b937e>] do_sync_write+0xe3/0x120
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff8104c6af>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x34
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff810c311f>] ? getname+0x2c/0x13c
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff810b9e3f>] vfs_write+0xad/0x172
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff810c30ea>] ? putname+0x2d/0x36
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff810ba016>] sys_write+0x49/0xc1
[  172.197002]  [<ffffffff8100bafb>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  172.197002] Code:  Bad RIP value.
[  172.197002] RIP  [<(null)>] (null)
[  172.197002]  RSP <ffff88012be5b990>
[  172.197002] CR2: 0000000000000000
[  172.208796] ---[ end trace 76194948aab8609b ]---
[  172.209235] tar used greatest stack depth: 3560 bytes left
[  172.209307] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (null)
[  172.209314] IP: [<(null)>] (null)
[  172.209318] PGD 12c41b067 PUD 12e2db067 PMD 0
[  172.209335] Oops: 0010 [#2] SMP
[  172.209338] last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/net/venet0/uevent
[  172.209340] CPU 1
[  172.209342] Modules linked in: vznetdev vzrst vzcpt vzdquota vzmon vzdev sco rfcomm bnep l2cap btusb bluetooth [last unloaded: i2c_nforce2]
[  172.209352] Pid: 1934, comm: syslog-ng Tainted: G      D    2.6.32-openvz-budarin.1 #14 budarin System Product Name
[  172.209356] RIP: 0010:[<0000000000000000>]  [<(null)>] (null)
[  172.209360] RSP: 0018:ffff88012c73f990  EFLAGS: 00010246
[  172.209363] RAX: ffffffffa00899c0 RBX: ffff88012f7fe770 RCX: 000000000000000c
[  172.209366] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000003000 RDI: ffff88012f7fe770
[  172.209369] RBP: ffff88012c73f9f8 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 0000000000000018
[  172.209372] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000002700 R12: ffff88012b4323f0
[  172.209375] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff88012f7fe6c0 R15: ffff88012f7fea68
[  172.209379] FS:  00007f8e28346700(0000) GS:ffff880028280000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  172.209383] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  172.209386] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 000000012bc83000 CR4: 00000000000006a0
[  172.209389] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[  172.209392] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[  172.209396] Process syslog-ng (pid: 1934, veid=0, threadinfo ffff88012c73e000, task ffff88012bd47620)
[  172.209399] Stack:
[  172.209400]  ffffffff81137cb8 ffff88012e067c00 0000000000000002 0000000000000003
[  172.209404] <0> ffffffffffff0000 ffff88012f7fe770 0000000000000000 ffff88012c73f9f8
[  172.209408] <0> ffffea0004a74000 0000000000000030 0000000000001000 ffff88012c73fa98
[  172.209412] Call Trace:
[  172.209416]  [<ffffffff81137cb8>] ? ext4_da_get_block_prep+0x138/0x28c
[  172.209421]  [<ffffffff810dbbcd>] __block_prepare_write+0x1b2/0x392
[  172.209425]  [<ffffffff81137b80>] ? ext4_da_get_block_prep+0x0/0x28c
[  172.209430]  [<ffffffff81085011>] ? add_to_page_cache_locked+0x75/0xb6
[  172.209434]  [<ffffffff810dbf2e>] block_write_begin+0x7b/0xcd
[  172.209438]  [<ffffffff811378a7>] ext4_da_write_begin+0x15b/0x1e8
[  172.209442]  [<ffffffff81137b80>] ? ext4_da_get_block_prep+0x0/0x28c
[  172.209446]  [<ffffffff81085a1a>] generic_file_buffered_write+0x104/0x275
[  172.209450]  [<ffffffff81086040>] __generic_file_aio_write+0x34d/0x382
[  172.209456]  [<ffffffff810c85d9>] ? pollwake+0x0/0x4f
[  172.209459]  [<ffffffff810860d3>] generic_file_aio_write+0x5e/0xa8
[  172.209463]  [<ffffffff8112f289>] ext4_file_write+0x89/0x90
[  172.209467]  [<ffffffff81109b12>] ? kmsg_read+0x0/0x46
[  172.209472]  [<ffffffff810b937e>] do_sync_write+0xe3/0x120
[  172.209477]  [<ffffffff8104ea2f>] ? enqueue_hrtimer+0x65/0x72
[  172.209481]  [<ffffffff8104c6af>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x34
[  172.209487]  [<ffffffff8103cda6>] ? ns_to_timeval+0xd/0x28
[  172.209490]  [<ffffffff8104e9bd>] ? __remove_hrtimer+0x79/0x86
[  172.209494]  [<ffffffff8104f296>] ? hrtimer_try_to_cancel+0x6f/0x79
[  172.209498]  [<ffffffff810b9e3f>] vfs_write+0xad/0x172
[  172.209502]  [<ffffffff810ba016>] sys_write+0x49/0xc1
[  172.209507]  [<ffffffff8100bafb>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  172.209509] Code:  Bad RIP value.
[  172.209514] RIP  [<(null)>] (null)
[  172.209516]  RSP <ffff88012c73f990>
[  172.209518] CR2: 0000000000000000
[  172.209520] ---[ end trace 76194948aab8609c ]---
[  172.224073] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (null)
[  172.224344] IP: [<(null)>] (null)
[  172.224510] PGD 12e21c067 PUD 12e1db067 PMD 0
[  172.224510] Oops: 0010 [#3] SMP
[  172.224510] last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/net/venet0/uevent
[  172.224510] CPU 1
[  172.224510] Modules linked in: vznetdev vzrst vzcpt vzdquota vzmon vzdev sco rfcomm bnep l2cap btusb bluetooth [last unloaded: i2c_nforce2]
[  172.224510] Pid: 2249, comm: vzquota Tainted: G      D    2.6.32-openvz-budarin.1 #14 budarin System Product Name
[  172.224510] RIP: 0010:[<0000000000000000>]  [<(null)>] (null)
[  172.224510] RSP: 0018:ffff88012c73fc60  EFLAGS: 00010246
[  172.224510] RAX: ffffffffa00899c0 RBX: ffff88012b476f30 RCX: 000000000000000c
[  172.224510] RDX: ffff88012e067800 RSI: 0000000000003000 RDI: ffff88012b476f30
[  172.224510] RBP: ffff88012c73fcb8 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: 0000000000000003
[  172.224510] R10: 0000000000000008 R11: 0000000000000092 R12: ffffea0004a70240
[  172.224510] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffff88012b476e80
[  172.224510] FS:  00007f59dc642700(0000) GS:ffff880028280000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  172.224510] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  172.224510] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 000000012ce6e000 CR4: 00000000000006a0
[  172.224510] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[  172.224510] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[  172.224510] Process vzquota (pid: 2249, veid=0, threadinfo ffff88012c73e000, task ffff88012c62d460)
[  172.224510] Stack:
[  172.224510]  ffffffff81133aed ffff88012c73fcc8 ffffffff00000000 0000000000000003
[  172.224510] <0> ffff88012e067c00 ffff88012b477058 ffffea0004a70240 ffff88012b477050
[  172.224510] <0> ffff88012b477050 ffff88012c73fd28 ffffffffffffffff ffff88012c73fcc8
[  172.224510] Call Trace:
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff81133aed>] ? ext4_da_invalidatepage+0x177/0x19f
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff8108d5d0>] do_invalidatepage+0x20/0x22
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff8108db3f>] truncate_inode_page+0x46/0x82
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff8108dc45>] truncate_inode_pages_range+0xca/0x369
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffffa008414e>] ? vzquota_inode_data+0x3c/0xa4 [vzdquota]
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff81137934>] ? ext4_delete_inode+0x0/0x24c
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff8108def1>] truncate_inode_pages+0xd/0xf
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff81137992>] ext4_delete_inode+0x5e/0x24c
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff81137934>] ? ext4_delete_inode+0x0/0x24c
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff810ccebe>] generic_delete_inode+0xd5/0x162
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff810ccf62>] generic_drop_inode+0x17/0x62
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff810cbcc3>] iput+0x61/0x65
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff810c8b9a>] dentry_iput+0xb1/0xc1
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff810c8c81>] d_kill+0x40/0x60
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff810ca86a>] dput+0x1bb/0x1c8
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff810baa5a>] __fput+0x1ba/0x1e6
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff810baa9b>] fput+0x15/0x17
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff810b7a68>] filp_close+0x63/0x6d
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff810b7b09>] sys_close+0x97/0xcb
[  172.224510]  [<ffffffff8100bafb>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  172.224510] Code:  Bad RIP value.
[  172.224510] RIP  [<(null)>] (null)
[  172.224510]  RSP <ffff88012c73fc60>
[  172.224510] CR2: 0000000000000000
[  172.241398] ---[ end trace 76194948aab8609d ]---
[  172.243506] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (null)
[  172.243776] IP: [<(null)>] (null)
[  172.244001] PGD 12c538067 PUD 12e3c8067 PMD 0
[  172.244293] Oops: 0010 [#4] SMP
[  172.244448] last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/net/venet0/uevent
[  172.244448] CPU 0
[  172.244448] Modules linked in: vznetdev vzrst vzcpt vzdquota vzmon vzdev sco rfcomm bnep l2cap btusb bluetooth [last unloaded: i2c_nforce2]
[  172.244448] Pid: 2232, comm: vzctl Tainted: G      D    2.6.32-openvz-budarin.1 #14 budarin System Product Name
[  172.244448] RIP: 0010:[<0000000000000000>]  [<(null)>] (null)
[  172.244448] RSP: 0018:ffff88012c7dfc90  EFLAGS: 00010246
[  172.244448] RAX: ffffffffa00899c0 RBX: ffff88012b476390 RCX: 000000000000000c
[  172.244448] RDX: ffff88012e067800 RSI: 0000000000003000 RDI: ffff88012b476390
[  172.244448] RBP: ffff88012c7dfce8 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: 0000000000000003
[  172.244448] R10: ffffffff00000000 R11: ffff88012c7dfde8 R12: ffffea0004a71700
[  172.244448] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffff88012b4762e0
[  172.244448] FS:  00007ffd4526b700(0000) GS:ffff880028200000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  172.244448] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[  172.244448] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 000000012be59000 CR4: 00000000000006b0
[  172.244448] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[  172.244448] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[  172.244448] Process vzctl (pid: 2232, veid=0, threadinfo ffff88012c7de000, task ffff88012c62dcd0)
[  172.244448] Stack:
[  172.244448]  ffffffff81133aed ffff88012c7dfcf8 ffffffff00000000 0000000000000003
[  172.244448] <0> ffff88012e067c00 ffff88012b4764b8 ffffea0004a71700 ffff88012b4764b0
[  172.244448] <0> ffff88012b4764b0 ffff88012c7dfd58 ffffffffffffffff ffff88012c7dfcf8
[  172.244448] Call Trace:
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff81133aed>] ? ext4_da_invalidatepage+0x177/0x19f
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff8108d5d0>] do_invalidatepage+0x20/0x22
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff8108db3f>] truncate_inode_page+0x46/0x82
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff8108dc45>] truncate_inode_pages_range+0xca/0x369
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffffa008414e>] ? vzquota_inode_data+0x3c/0xa4 [vzdquota]
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff81137934>] ? ext4_delete_inode+0x0/0x24c
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff8108def1>] truncate_inode_pages+0xd/0xf
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff81137992>] ext4_delete_inode+0x5e/0x24c
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff81137934>] ? ext4_delete_inode+0x0/0x24c
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff810ccebe>] generic_delete_inode+0xd5/0x162
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff810ccf62>] generic_drop_inode+0x17/0x62
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff810cbcc3>] iput+0x61/0x65
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff810c45ce>] do_unlinkat+0x103/0x156
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff810bcf46>] ? sys_newlstat+0x1a/0x38
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff8144a61b>] ? do_page_fault+0x297/0x2c7
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff810c4632>] sys_unlink+0x11/0x13
[  172.244448]  [<ffffffff8100bafb>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  172.244448] Code:  Bad RIP value.
[  172.244448] RIP  [<(null)>] (null)
[  172.244448]  RSP <ffff88012c7dfc90>
[  172.244448] CR2: 0000000000000000
[  172.255431] ---[ end trace 76194948aab8609e ]---
```

Comment: run dmesg -c and then create the container and paste the output of dmesg after it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer to my own question...again

i looked into openvz bugs, and i found people already reported similar issues. this issue relates to the ext4 file system. even through the openvz wiki states that it is already stable on ext4, but it does not seem so.

to solve this issue, just turn off the 'disk quota' feature, by setting the 'DISK_QUOTA=no' in the /etc/vz/vz.conf file, the path may vary according to your distro.